# How to catch all subdomains in plesk

Tags: windows-server-2012, plesk, wildcard-subdomain

How to **catch all subdomains** in **plesk** which installed in windows server 2012 ?
I founded answer for Linux servers but not same config file and other settings in windows.
I want catch all subdomains like `*.domain.com` in one file like `domain.com/t.asp` which can detect entered subdomain in this file, and address in browser not change to this file address and show same `*.domain` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert an "A" DNS entry on your primary nameserver of your domain.

```
*.domain.com    A         XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Answer (score 2):

Only IIS 10 in Windows 2016 supports wildcard subdomains and you can create such subdomain in Plesk 17.

In Windows 2012 it's just not supported in IIS.

https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a new subdomain and name it as (`*.domain.com`) with the root folder pointing to your default domain folder (`httpdocs, in my case`).

Remember also set your SSL certificate in your *Hosting settings* link, if any.

You should now be able to try URLs such as: `one.domain.com`, `two.domain.com`, etc...